# Replace all invalid escape characters

Tags: scala

The scala StringContext has problems with invlaid escape characters. Example:

```
s"""v \C/R\ni"""
```

Raises "scala.StringContext$InvalidEscapeException: invalid escape character at index 2".
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.StringContext$$InvalidEscapeException

Is there an elegant and universal way to avoid this problem? Especially the *valid* escape characters should be preserved. Possible would be:

```
s"""v \\C/R\ni"""
```

Just for info: I'll pipe such strings into a scala interpreter, so it is possible to prepare the string.

At a pinch replace * with \* but not the ones from [chapter 1.3.6](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) will do.
Any clever ideas?

(I'm using scala 2.11.x)

Comment: I want to say "use regex" but I haven't found the exact char sequence to do so yet; but that seems to me to be the way to go, match on every valid escape character, and replace every invalid one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution at the moment:

```
val regex = "\\\\[^btnfr\"]".r
var str = """hi \C ho \t jo \n \" mu \M"""
val matches = regex.findAllIn(str).toList
val chars = matches.map(_(1))
for ( (x,y) <- matches zip chars) str = str.replace(x, "\\\\" + y)
```

The output is """hi \C ho \t jo \n \" mu \M""".
Not very elegant, but it works. Maybe someone has an better, more "functional" solution?